# How to save Tensorflow variables which assigned value by another Tensorflow variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to ternary weights in Resnet using Tensorflow ,and code is here [Tenary_Conv2D](https://github.com/erdollar/TWN/blob/master/Tenary_Conv2D.py).
I can see Tenary_W is -1,0,+1,but can't saver it correctly in checkpoint.
I just simply save all TF variables.

The Tenary weights is here [Tenary weights histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wE4h.png).

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Save `Tenary_W` as separate checkpoint? [Here is saving and restoring tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore) and you can check out how to save specified variables.

Comment: I want to save `Tenary_W` as separate. like this page, I know that Tensorflow only save tf variables.[if i want to save something like inc_v1 as checkpoint ,what i can do?](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#saving_variables).